# React - use ref in component AND pass it to parent in props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Update: my problem was actually due to typos – the general approach works fine if you'd like to use a child element ref in both a child and parent component.

Here's a working example of the approach that works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rwj7z7o7oo

---

Original post:

I'm trying to forward a ref to the parent component, while also making the ref accessible for functions in the child (which is a class). Currently, I can successfully pass the ref to the parent, but the ref is no longer accessible in the child.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    // Unable to access the forwarded ref here:
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.forwardedRef); // null
    }

    render() {
        return <input type="text" ref={this.props.forwardedRef} />
    }
}

// Parent is able to access the ref:
const Parent = () => {
    const childRef = useRef(null);

    function handleClick() {
        console.log(childRef.current); // correctly ref's the input el
    }

    return (
        <Child forwardedRef={childRef} onClick={handleClick} />
    );
}
```

Is there another approach will let me use the ref in both Child and Parent?

Comment: You wish to pass the child's ref up to the parent but your current code is not working, correct?

Comment: Hi Shawn - yes, in the example code, the child's ref is successfully passed up to the parent, but the ref is not accessible in the child itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`useRef` returns values that are like instance variables classes. In your case, there is nothing that would cause the component to render even if your set the ref and hence componentDidUpdate of child wouldn't run.

Also you haven't returned anything from Child component.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  // Unable to access the forwarded ref here:
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.forwardedRef); // null
    console.log(prevProps.forwardedRef); // null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="text" ref={this.props.forwardedRef} />
        <div>{this.props.count}</div>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.props.onClick} value={"Click"} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// Parent is able to access the ref:
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(childRef.current); // correctly ref's the input el
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }

  return <Child forwardedRef={childRef} count={count} onClick={handleClick} />;
};
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5kw376nx1p)**

Comment: Thanks Shubham – I don't use class components much and made a mistake. You can substitute componentDidMount (I edited my original question). I also added 'return' to the Child's render function, thanks for pointing out the typo. The main issue I'm trying to solve is that the ref isn't available for use in any child functions.

Comment: Ah thanks Shubham - your correction of my typos helped me figure it out. I forgot that componentDidUpdate doesn't run on the initial render of the component.

Comment: @Stephen, Even componentDidMount  is called on initial render and since the ref of the parent will update but no re-render is called to update props it isn't reflecting in componentDidMount.

Comment: I believe Child will break if parent did not pass ref.

Answer (score 6):

## React Hooks

No need to pass `forwardedRef` in React hooks.

You can access `ref` variable directly in `forwardRef` function:

```js
const Child = React.forwardRef((_props, ref) => {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        "<span>Ref works in child</span>"
      );
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div className="child" ref={ref}>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
    </div>
  );
});

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (childRef.current) {
      childRef.current.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterbegin",
        "<span>Ref works in parent</span>"
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.child {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  color: #777;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```